# value joda is not a member of org

Tags: scala

I'm new to Scala and would like to do the DateTime using joda.

In [Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/23M5tOhySTqLtK43Obv3KQ) (an online Scala IDE) I wrote this:

```
import org.joda.time.{DateTime}
```

But I got the error as the title.
I have the same error in my local IDE (IntelliJ). Please help me with this. Thank you.

Comment: You haven't installed/included the library properly. Are you sure Scastie supports joda-time?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you mean by that. Maybe I need to include some other things before?

Comment: Go to `build settings` and use `addSbtPlugin` to add the joda-time plugin.

Comment: I made it more explicit in my answer. Let me know if you get it working :)

Comment: Thank you. This is a great help :)

Comment: Why use a plugin? If you use a supported JVM you have to have a `java.time`. If you are on unsupported JVM and cannot do anything about it, [add a library](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/joda-time/joda-time). And which JVM you use is pretty much determined by your version of Scala.

Comment: I'm refactoring the legacy code from others. And I'm only on the first step which is being able to run the code. That's why I try to stick to the convention at this stage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to use something from this library: https://search.maven.org/artifact/joda-time/joda-time/2.10.13/jar

You can include this library in Scastie using the following line:

```
addSbtPlugin("joda-time" % "joda-time" % "2.10.13")
```

You can add this line by going to `Build Settings` in Scastie and entering the line in the `Extra Sbt Configuration` section.